# r qqp function - why is the 'perfect fit' a flat line on 0?

Tags: r

This may be more of a statistical question than a programming one. I just wanted to make sure I was getting the programming right first.

I have a large count dataset (108 sites with 31 species = 3348 observations) but a lot of these are 0 counts because only not species were not present at every site. I have had log transformation suggested to me but others have also said that you shouldn't log transform count data. Here is my data for the first 8 species (also contains the very abundant species with the highest counts):

```
example.abund <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
               0,0,1,0,8,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
               0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,1,0,0,0,0,
               0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
               0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
               0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
               0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,0,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
               2,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,
               0,1,0,0,0,28,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,
               0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,0,1,0,0,8,7,7,1,1,13,0,8,0,3,0,1,1,
               1,4,4,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,6,5,2,0,2,58,4,2,47,4,0,0,0,2,59,2,0,0,6,1,36,28,2,
               1,1,0,6,0,0,2,5,0,0,0,0,87,7,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,6,11,0,0,0,3,0,4,0,7,2,
               0,5,0,4,1,0,1,12,0,2,0,9,0,1,0,0,0,24,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
               0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
               0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
               0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,15,0,2,
               81,0,1,32,26,13,2,61,0,66,2,2,0,17,43,43,0,25,19,2,25,26,91,61,0,13,0,62,186,1,4,22,1,50,3,67,86,11,56,26,74,0,6,8,7,0152,8,14,1,97,1,0,12,11,3,1,1,112,2,35,36,5,61,26,211,15,8,173,17,97,22,18,88,11,1,66,15,3,3,3,2,0,1,0,41,9,14,1,0,38,0,0,51,27,11,38,31,1,0,221,68,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,29,0,0,0,0,
               0,82,12,0,0,3,0,9,0,0,164,0,0,0,0,1,0,15,0,0,0,6,56,0,0,0,6,0,0,1,0,5,5,8,
               0,4,0,0,6,0,0,2,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,683,0,0,0,0,3,149,252,11,13,195,19,0,59,0,0,1,28,0,
               0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,31,55,85,0,142,0,44,52,0,0192,0,45,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,2,0,0,6,
               0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,19,3,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
               0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

I am need to make a mixed model to fit the data, but first I am trying to figure out the most appropriate distribution to use. I was following the steps in this [blog](http://www.juliapilowsky.com/mixedmodels/). But all of the red lines (meant to represent 'perfect fit' for that distribution) are coming up as being 0 along the entire plot.

My question is: have a coded this correctly and there are so many 0s in my data that the perfect fit is 0? Or is there something wrong with the way I have coded?

Code example:

```
#so that the families without 0s can recognise data
example.abund.1 <- example.abund + 1 
plot(hist(example.abund))

qqp(example.abund, "norm")

qqp(example.abund.1, "lnorm") #lognorm

#have to generate estimates of parameters:
nbinom <- fitdistr(example.abund.1, "Negative Binomial")
qqp(example.abund.1, "nbinom", size = nbinom$estimate[[1]], mu = nbinom$estimate[[2]])

poisson <- fitdistr(example.abund.1, "Poisson")
qqp(example.abund.1, "pois", poisson$estimate)

gamma <- fitdistr(example.abund.1, "gamma")
qqp(example.abund.1, "gamma", shape = gamma$estimate[[1]], rate = gamma$estimate[[2]])
```

Comment: Did you check `range()` on all your inputs to `qqp` to make sure there's something nonzero in there?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Carl. I have checked that now, unfortunately the range is matches the dataset, 0 683. Thanks though.